# Error while applying OOPM in python

Tags: python

First of all I am new to python programming.
Here is my code:-

```
class login_ok(object):
    """docstring for instalogin"""
 def __init__(self):
 pass

def open_website(self,websiteName):
print(websiteName)


def login(self,email,password):
print(email)



def search(self,searchVariable):
print(searchVariable)


login1 = login_ok()
web = "a"
email_pass = "c"
password_pass = "b"
search_variable = "d"
login1.open_website(web)
login1.login(email_pass,password_pass)
login1.search(search_variable)
```

I am using sublime and i am getting this error 'login_ok' object has no attribute 'open_website' .

Comment: There are numerous indentation errors in that code. Correct indentation is _vital_ in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Python.

You have some basic indentation problems, which are fundamental to how Python works. I'd recommend you going through some tutorials and learning stages to help get the basics right.

Here's a link to a good place to start:
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/intro/learning/

And by way of example, here are just a couple of examples of fixed errors:

```
class login_ok(object):
    """docstring for instalogin"""
    def __init__(self):
        # For example, all the code defined within a method or function is indented.
        pass

    # Similarly, all methods defined 'within' a class need to be indented four spaces.
    def open_website(self,websiteName):
        # Through proper indentation, you're telling the Python interpreter
        # that `open_website` is a method of the parent `login_ok` class
        print(websiteName)
```

Comment: I was using tabs instead of four spaces. Thanks

Comment: In case you haven't already seen it, there's a convenient way to set the tabs to spaces in the bottom left corner of the Sublime Text window. It will either read "Tab size: {number}" or "Spaces: {number}" depending on current settings.

Comment: Sublime is showing me "Tab size:4".Does that mean if I press tab key once I will get 4 spaces? I used tab and spaces(both) while writing above code. Since "Tab size:4" equals to 4 times pressing of space bar.Why did I got error?I removed all the spaces created by tabs and used spaces created by space bar which fixed my problem.

Comment: You need to change the setting by ticking the "Indent using spaces" option in that menu. The reason for this is that the 'Tab' just inserts a special character, which each piece of software interprets differently. Python insists on 4 explicit 'space' characters, so this setting in Sublime overrides the tab key and inserts 4 spaces instead which is the right behaviour for Python.

Answer (score 0):

While defining your class, you are defining its methods as unrelated functions outside of its scope. In order for your methods to be within the scope of your class, they would need to be written as follows:

```
class login_ok(object):
    """docstring for instalogin"""
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def open_website(self,websiteName):
        print(websiteName)

    def login(self,email,password):
        print(email)

    def search(self,searchVariable):
        print(searchVariable)
```

You can use either tabs or spaces to indent, but you must be consistent and not mix them. You may want to read further documentation on [Variables and Scope](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) and [Classes](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Classes.html) in order to get a better understanding of how to structure your programs. The style in which you write Python is directly related to its functionality as its lack of braces means that scope is defined by indentation.